# Overriding __eq__ in Python: How does switching of arguments order happen?

Tags: python

The following code tests parts of a dictionary. The idea is, that only the keys available in the `TestDict` are checked. Other keys should be ignored. What troubles me, are the two asserts at the bottom:

Both comparisons work fine. For the first one, I expected this. The `TestDict` is on the left, so his `__eq__` is called. But I would have expected the second one to fail, as I assumed it would not call the `__eq__` of `TestDict`. Obviously Python is smart enough to switch the order of the arguments. Can somebody explain the exact rules to me?

```
class TestDict(dict):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "other:", other
        for key, val in self.items():
            if callable(val):
                return val(other[key])
            else:
                return val == other[key]

ref = TestDict(
    a=5,
    b=lambda x: x > 5
)

result = dict(
    a=5,
    b=9,
    c=10
)

assert ref == result
assert result == ref
```

Comment: Note that `result.__eq__(ref)` is `False`; the reflection doesn't happen if you call the method directly. `x == y` is interpreted as `x.__eq__(y) or y.__eq__(z)`.

Comment: Sure. The `print` shows me, that the correct `__eq__` is called in both cases. But I'm curious why and how the exact rules are.